# delphi database without sql server

Tags: sql, delphi

I need to do make small database apps with DELPHI.
Can I do them without using any SQL servers ?

I ask that because I want to avoid SQL server installing in the target machine

Does DELPHI has a built in engine that can replace SQL server ?

Comment: Check this out: http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvCsvDataSet

Comment: More important, what do you actually need? SQL querying capabilities or just single table storage that you can filter/sort/view in a grid?

Comment: Is it a single user or multiuser database application ? There is a big difference.

Comment: mORMot is not traditional approach for Delphi but might possibly provide you a scale-up later https://tamingthemormot.wordpress.com/2015/07/03/introduction/

Answer (score 2):

Make use of **FireDAC** and **SQLite**

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Connect_to_SQLite_database_(FireDAC)

SQLite works on any platform

https://www.sqlite.org/

Answer (score 2):

For windows, you can [use Firebird Embebded](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5-1/).

You only need copy some files in the application directory for use it.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

FireDAC has Local SQL feature. You can use in-memory database with TFDMemTables component which ships with newer versions of Delphi, or use TClientDataSet. Also google on embedded database with Delphi if you need a more powerful solution.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Local_SQL_%28FireDAC%29

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TClientDataSet component

Comment: This requires that you redistribute a few extra binary dlls, and has the disadvantage of not storing the results in clear text, but it would do.  I personally prefer my own `TJvCsvDataSet` which is a CSV file dataset that is built into the Jedi JVCL with zero extra binary redistributables, and a plain text format that is an open standard, readable by thousands of tools.  But whatever.

Comment: @WarrenP I considered that it should be a built in engine (included with Delphi). IIRC TClientDataSet does not need any DLL besides midas.dll (which can be ommitted by including the MidasLib)

Comment: Oh yes, that's a good idea.